# Selenium java Maven how to execute Testcase with fillo qry data driven framework

Tags: java, selenium

Testcase file. Testcase with fillo query data driven

Suppose when the query (String qry="Select * from Sheet1 where ACC='M' and GEN='F'";) returns 5 data rows for one test case and i want to use the same qry for the next case but with different data  row

```
public class Testcases {
    public WebDriver driver;
    Fillo fillo;
    static ExtentReports report;
    ExtentTest test;
    //String PAGE_URL = "Your_page_Url";

    @BeforeClass public static void allTestsPrep(){     
        report  = new ExtentReports("Report.html",true);
    }

    @AfterClass public static void allTestCleanUp() {
        report.flush();
    }


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        String browserName = getParameter("browser");   
        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){        
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } 
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();}
        else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {              
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }   
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // driver.get(PAGE_URL);
    }

    @Test 
    public void Testcase001() throws FilloException, InterruptedException {
        String qry="Select * from Sheet1 where ACC='M' and GEN='F'";
        test = report.startTest("Testcase 1 - Test findpage");
        Useragreement usragr = new Useragreement(driver);
        usragr.CheckboxSelectall();             
        test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "VERIFIED");//report          
    }

    @After
    public void close() { 
        driver.close(); 
        test = null;
    }

    private String getParameter(String name) {
        String value = System.getProperty(name);

        if (value == null)
            throw new RuntimeException(name + " is not a parameter!");
        if (value.isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException(name + " is empty!");

        return value;
    }
}
```

Fillo file
Now the code will be `FILLO.inputText(Phone_Number,"Pno",qry)``;

```
public class FILLOAPP {
    public static String getTestValue(String fieldName, String qry) throws FilloException{
        String testString=xlTesting(fieldName,qry);
        return testString;
    }   
    public static String xlTesting(String fieldName, String qry) throws FilloException{
        String testval=null;
        Fillo fillo=new Fillo();

        Connection connection=fillo.getConnection("resources/TestData.xlsx");
        String sqry=qry;
        Recordset recordset=connection.executeQuery(sqry);

        while(recordset.next()){
            ArrayList<String> dataColl=recordset.getFieldNames();
            Iterator<String> dataIterator=dataColl.iterator();

            while(dataIterator.hasNext()){
                for (int i=0;i<=dataColl.size()-1;i++){
                    String data=dataIterator.next();
                    String dataVal=recordset.getField(data);
                    if (data.equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)){
                        String testData=dataColl.get(i);   
                        String testValue= recordset.getField(testData);
                        testval=testValue;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        recordset.close();
        connection.close();
        return testval; 
    }

    public static void inputText(WebElement driver, String fieldName, String  qry) throws FilloException{
        String fval=getTestValue(fieldName, qry);
        driver.sendKeys(fval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String dataRead(String sheetname, String testcaseid, String header) throws IOException {
        String value = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
            book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            sheet = book.getSheet(sheetname);
            int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            // System.out.println(lastRowNum);
            int lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            // System.out.println(lastCellNum);
            for (int i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {

                for (int j = 1; j < lastCellNum; j++) {

                    Map<String, Map<String, String>> excelmap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
                    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).toString(), sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(j).toString());
                    excelmap.put(sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).toString(), map);
                    if (excelmap.containsKey(testcaseid)) {
                        Map<String, String> w = excelmap.get(testcaseid);
                        if (map.containsKey(header)) {
                            value = w.get(header).toString();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception E) {
        }

        return value;
    }

    public void excelWrite(String sheetname, String testcaseid, int columnno, String value) throws Throwable {
        File file = new File(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetname);
        // sheetnoOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
        int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
            Map<Map<String, String>, String> excelmap = new HashMap<Map<String, String>, String>();
            LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).toString(), sheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).toString());
            if (map.containsValue(testcaseid)) {
                excelmap.put(map, value);
                String w = map.get("TestCase ID");
                Map<String, String> fin = new HashMap<String, String>();
                fin.put(w, value);
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i + 1);
                Cell createcell = row.createCell(columnno);
                createcell.setCellValue(value);

            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fis.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map ReadExcelExecution() throws Throwable {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("IssuePolicy");
            int TotalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int noOfColumns = (sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells() - 1);
            int lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
//      System.out.println(TotalRow);
//      System.out.println(noOfColumns);
//      System.out.println(lastCellNum);
            map.put("1",
                    new Object[] { "TestCase ID", "PolicyNo", "IssueDate", "Accumulated Value", "GMWB Type",
                            "MAWA/2LMAWA", "Remaining MAWA", "Protected Income Payment", "Accumulated Value DOD",
                            "DataComparison", "Comments" });
            for (int i = 1; i <= TotalRow; i++) {
                {
                    String testcaseid = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString();
                    String policyno = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(noOfColumns).toString();
                    String issuedate = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2).toString();
                    String values = null;
                    map.put(testcaseid, new Object[] { testcaseid, policyno, issuedate, values, values, values, values,
                            values, values, values, values });

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception E) {
        }
        return map;

    }

    public void writinginInputFile(String sheetname, Map mapvalue) throws Throwable {
        // write excel file and file name is SaveTestNGResultToExcel.xls
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetname);
        keyset = mapvalue.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = (Object[]) ReadExcelExecution().get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if (obj instanceof Date)
                    cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                else if (obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);

            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(TESTDATA_SHEET_PATH));
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully saved Selenium WebDriver TestNG result to Excel File!!!");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package seleniumproject;

import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Multiplewindowpopup {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                                WebDriver driver;
                                String Userdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",Userdir+"\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
                                driver = new ChromeDriver(); // launch chrome
                                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

                                driver.get("http://www.popuptest.com/goodpopups.html");

                                //find ID of the 2nd link

                                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Good PopUp #2")).click();


                                Set<String> windowhandler = driver.getWindowHandles();

                                Iterator<String> myiterator = windowhandler.iterator();

//////////////             //how to get index of parent and child window ???







                //now we have two window IDs and moving the window from parent to child.
                                driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

                                 System.out.println("child window title"+driver.getTitle());

                                 //closing the child window
                                driver.close();

                                 // comming back to parentwindow
                                driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
                                System.out.println("parent window title"+driver.getTitle());


   }

}
```